# Application Shutdown

Tags: c#

I have a project that I prepared with C#.
When the program runs, it checks for the first update.
If yes, “Update?” he asks.

If the user approves, it downloads the different update program in the background and closes the running program,
switches to the update program and starts the update.
However, sometimes the program hangs in the background for a while after it closes.
The error occurs because it cannot delete files.

How can I close the hung program or how can I delete related files?

```
foreach (Process clsProcess in Process.GetProcesses())
{
    if (clsProcess.ProcessName.Equals("ExampleApp"))
    {
        clsProcess.Kill();
    }
}
Directory.Delete(@"C:\ExampleAppFiles", true); //Problem blok
```

Comment: System.Windows.Application.Current.Shutdown();

Answer (score 0):

This should be checked by using Mutexes. Your first application should create a mutex and destroy it when shutdown. The installer should check for this mutex somehow like this:

```
static void Main() 
{
  using(Mutex mutex = new Mutex(false, @"Global\myMutexName"))
  {
    if(!mutex.WaitOne(0, false))
    {
       MessageBox.Show("Instance already running");
       return;
    }
  }
}
```